# Desenvolvimento desktop com Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, aplicação-desktop, electron

Com o crescimento da `web` muitas pessoas abandonaram o desenvolvimento desktop, porém algumas tecnologias interessantes surgiram, como o [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/#built-on-electron):

> Electron permite criar aplicações desktop com puro JavaScript através
>   de um runtime com APIs ricas e nativas. Você pode ver isso como uma
>   variação do runtime do io.js que é focado em aplicações desktop em vez
>   de web servers.

Diante disso surgiram algumas dúvidas:

1. Quais os pontos positivos e negativos ao se desenvolver com
   `Electron`? Ou seja, em que ele se destaca?
2. Visto que o desenvolvimento com `Electron` é baseado em tecnologia web
   isso pode interferir no desempenho do aplicativo `desktop`? Ou
   seria uma vantagem?

Comment: Em relação a que?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pontos Positivos:

1. Desenvolvedores já conhecedores de linguagens para web não vão precisar aprender uma nova linguagem.
2. Aplicativos não dependem de internet para funcionar. Muito bom quando a internet é lenta ou não existe. Ou mesmo para casos que a internet cai.
3. Aplicações que rodam localmente rodam mais rápido e não vão sobrecarregar o servidor em casos de muitos clientes.
4. Aplicações web dependem de navegador (e isso é muito chato, quem desenvolve para web sabe), neste caso este problema é eliminado. Você não precisa se preocupar qual navegador o cliente vai usar.

Pontos Negativos:

1. Desenvolvedores desktop tem que aprender linguagens web para desenvolver.
2. Você não tem componentes prontos da mesma forma que tem para desktop. Apesar de que este cenário está mudando com alguns frameworks CSS/JS.
3. Você não tem IDE's RAD para arrastar componentes prontos e desenvolver as telas do sistema.
4. O resultado é uma aplicação desktop e tem os seus problemas como atualizar a versão dentre outros.

---

O problema maior é o acesso aos recursos do computador local. As linguagens web (normal)
Mas é possível que estes frameworks ofereçam recursos para tal.

Comment: Entendi, esses recursos seriam os recursos nativos do SO, por exemplo: abrir a calculadora.

Comment: Também, mas estava pensando em arquivos, pastas, dispositivos conectados ao computador como impressora, webcam etc.