# Quais as linguagens atuais utilizadas para desenvolvimento de aplicações para Windows?

Tags: windows, característica-linguagem, gui

Quais as linguagens atuais utilizadas para desenvolvimento de aplicações para Windows?

Gostaria de saber as que possuem dependências, como o Java que precisa instalar o JRE ou algumas .NET que precisam que instale o .NET Framework previamente, assim como as que rodam sem nenhum instalação anterior.

Especificamente gostaria de saber linguagens que são utilizadas nas aplicações com interface gráfica (GUI).

> Essa pergunta pode servir como um guia para programadores que querem começar a desenvolver para Desktop Windows.

Encorajada por essa pergunta: [Qual a linguagem de programação para criar aplicações Android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174598/qual-a-linguagem-de-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-para-criar-aplica%c3%a7%c3%b5es-android)

Comment: Linguagens de programação são uma coisa UI são APIs ou recursos de outras coisas, uma coisa não tem nada haver com a outra, por exemplo, os elementos visuais nativos de apps Android são "gerados" pelo sistema operacional (parte dele) e manipulados pela linguagem Java, mas vc pode usar o NDK que é em C++, logo os elementos gerados são da mesma origem, mas o manipulador é que são linguagens diferentes, tirando linguagens voltadas para gerar exclusivamente imagens e recursos visuais me parece que toda e qualquer linguagem faz uso de APIs e UI não é parte da linguagem em si.

Comment: Outro exemplo é o Electron, é JavaScript a linguagem, mas os recursos visuais são HTML+CSS, ou seja, nem são elementos do sistema operacional, é um navegador com cara de programa de "verdade"

Comment: Obrigado pela informação @GuilhermeNascimento, não sabia disso. Pensei que a interface gráfica fazia parte da linguagem de programação.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essencialmente todas podem ser usadas de JavaScript à C, passando pelas citadas na pergunta, e obviamente C++, Delphi, Python e outras, não faz sentido listar todas.

Aí caímos no tipo de aplicação que usará, o Windows é muito libertário e permite todo tipo, para cada tipo haverá uma linguagem mais adequada. Vou concentrar em GUI.

## Web GUI

Se for usar JavaScript pode fazer para rodar na web mesmo, em um *browser*, [PWA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153860/101), [Webview](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/426505/101) em outra aplicação ou algo que suporte tecnologias web, como o [Electron](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96279/101). Alguns dirão que isso é fazer para web e não para Windows, mas se ele roda no Windows é para o Windows e está fazendo GUI.

## Scripts e dependentes

Diversas linguagens de *script* podem ser usadas para fazer diversas tarefas, mas se for criar uma aplicação desktop com GUI complica um pouco. Não é que elas não permitem, mas [raramente é tão adequado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107280/101).Algumas deixam bem a desejar, como o JS se for GUI nativa, o PHP que tem como mas [o resultado é bem ruim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/133375/101), e outras porque tem o problema de ter que mandar todos os *scripts* em vez de mandar um executável para que parece ser uma preocupação (algumas até possuem alguma forma como Python faz).

Para GUI Java nunca se deu muito bem porque parece um pato (anda, nada e voa, nenhum bem), roda em todas plataformas mas em todas não roda bem, mas [é uma opção razoável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52644/101).

## Sem instalação

Se realmente quer só o executável tem que pensar em linguagens como [C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80324/101), [C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134027/101), Rust, Go, Delphi, e até Lua ou [Harbour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43902/101) (eu sei que quase ninguém usa, mas é usada e gosto de citar) dependendo de como faça.

Claro que faz pouco sentido usar C pra muita coisa GUI complexa. Go ou mesmo Rust não tem histórico de uso com GUI. Delphi é proprietária e hoje em dia isso é um problema, mas tem GUI boa. C++ não é para qualquer um trabalhar. Cada uma tem um problema.

A Qt é uma biblioteca muita usada e veja os [*bindings* disponíveis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_language_bindings_for_Qt_4) para ela que portanto fazem dessas linguagens candidatas à tarefa descrita na pergunta. A Qt é das mais interessantes, embora eu acho que ela andou tomando um rumo complicado, melhorou em vários pontos, mas estagnou em outro e piorou em vários alguns.

Outro *framework* usado é o [WxWidgets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_language_bindings_for_wxWidgets), veja a lista de *bindings*.

Não vou listar todos os *frameworks* até porque alguns são pouco usados, muitos são usáveis de forma muito ruim apesar da linguagem suportá-lo em um *binding*, teria que fazer uma análise profunda em cada um. Se quiser tem uma [lista de vários *toolkits*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits) (não inclui *frameworks* que rodam em cima deles).

O .NET se encaixa bem porque a Microsoft faz dele o *flagship* para GUI, mas mesmo aí tem dificuldade de escolha porque temos 3 opções oficiais (Windows Forms, WPF e WinUI) e [outras extras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/226539/101) (algumas funcionam fora do Windows ou funcionam em cima da GUI nativa da plataforma que está rodando).

Existem alguns produtos que rodam em várias plataformas, entre elas o Windows, um exemplo da próprio Microsoft é o [Xamarin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90871/101) e [MAUI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Entre essas é possível usar a API Win32 pura para GUI mas literalmente ninguém faz isso, não é algo palatável e nem é considerado uma opção real.

E o .NET não precisa mais estar instalado na máquina para funcionar. Na verdade [essa forma de *deploy* já pode ser considerada legada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101). Então C# é das mais usadas e VB.NET era considerada, mas ela não tem futuro. F# ou outras linguagens que rodem no .NET podem ser usadas, mas na prática não são.

## Conclusão

Mas não posso deixar de dizer que a linguagem não importa mas sim o ecossistema em volta delas, isso é o que definirá o que é interessante para essa tarefa ou não, você escolhe o *framework* que usará e aí vê qual é a melhor linguagem para a tarefa.

Veja [Critérios para escolher linguagem para uso específico considerando o desempenho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/284715/101) e [Há algum problema em usar Java para aplicação de automação comercial no dektop? Ou é melhor fazer para web usando PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136702/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Oficialmente são mantidas [quatro tecnologias](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/choose-your-platform) pela Microsoft:

- **Windows Universal** - cujo é a última tecnologia da Microsoft feita essencialmente para dispositivos que funcionam no Windows 10. Estes aplicativos podem ser nativos na plataforma ou infundidos em aplicações .NET Core.

  Inclui desenvolvimento em [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [f#](/questions/tagged/f%23), [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net), [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) e [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).
- **Windows Forms e XAML** - é uma tecnologia legado, mas ainda utilizado, onde suas aplicações dependem do .NET Framework para serem executadas. O XAML utiliza uma linguagem de design parecida com o XML para prototipação de interfaces.

  Inclui desenvolvimento em [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [f#](/questions/tagged/f%23) e [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net).
- **Windows API** - também conhecido como *Win32 API* - são os aplicativos nativos, feitos para rodar em qualquer ambiente no Windows. São feitos essencialmente para aplicativos que requerem uma comunicação direta com algum driver ou hardware ou necessita de uma performance não-gerenciada.

  Inclui desenvolvimento em [c](/questions/tagged/c) e [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Existem outras tecnologias de terceiros, mas não vou citar elas aqui. Acima estou descrevendo qual o escopo de cada uma. O Windows Universal pode abranger todos dispositivos que rodem o Windows 10, incluindo Xbox, computadores ou televisões. Os outros são para escopos um pouco mais limitados.

[Levaram o Windows Forms para o .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms). A teoria é que as interfaces funcionem em multi-plataforma.

Comment: *"Windows 32" são aplicativos puro e nativos?* Talvez esteja falando de "Win32 API" e não "Windows 32", eu posso supor que possivelmente muitas coisas usem internamente em windows o "Win32 API" e nem nos damos conta. PS: o nome acho que agora é apenas "Windows API", não sei quando mudaram.

Comment: Vou fazer algumas colocações para não induzir a erro quem for ler e não conhecer o assunto: A página da Microsoft só fala do que interessa a ela e não lista tudo o que existe. Windows Universal não é um *toolkit* ou *framework* GUI, é uma denominação usada para aplicações que rodam em cima da plataforma UWP. Parte disso não é GUI (parece que queria listar as GUIs). Outras linguagens rodam nela, em tese qualquer poderia se fizer *binding* para essa API. Tenho minhas dúvidas se JS ainda é suportado, ou pelo menos evoluído. Windows Forms é um *framework* com *binding* que roda em cima de Win32.

Comment: XAML estritamente é a linguagem declarativa usada em algumas GUIs diferentes, entre elas o WPF que talvez seja o que quis usar. Ela é usada em outras como era no Silverlight, algumas formas do Xamarin, produtos de terceiros e no UWP. Na verdade a parte do UWP que é GUI chama WinUI e agora roda fora do UWP. É a tecnologia que a Microsoft está investindo em GUI atualmente. WPF parece ser considerada *done* (terá alguma evolução se o Visual Studio precisar) e Windows Forms terá alguma melhoria, mas não espere grandes investimentos.

Comment: A Win32 e não WIndows 32 é a API básica do Windows e podemos dizer que não existe uma GUI que não a use de uma forma ou de outra, ainda que evite o seu próprio *toolkit*. Então há *bindings* para ela em todas as linguagens que tem GUI no Windows. Quase ninguém programa na Win32 de verdade a não ser algo bem trivial e específica, ela é usada para construir outros *frameworks*. Não é só o Windows Forms que roda no .NET Core, o WPF e WinUI também, sem falar nos produtos de terceiros.

Comment: @Maniero se quiser fazer as devidas edições para complementar, eu agradeceria.